# Kafka consumer error after node failure

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We're testing a node failure scenario, on a 3 instance kafka cluster, with replication factor of 2.

After deleting an instance, the consumer is constantly failing.

The consumer is using kafka streams to read messages

Thanks

This is the consumer failure log:

```
08:09:19.667 [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] ERROR o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - User provided listener org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$RebalanceListener for group ComponentsActivityEventsStream failed on partition assignment

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Store ComponentsActivityStore's change log (ComponentsActivityEventsStream-ComponentsActivityStore-changelog) does not contain partition 0

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StoreChangelogReader.validatePartitionExists(StoreChangelogReader.java:87)

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.register(ProcessorStateManager.java:165)

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.register(AbstractProcessorContext.java:100)

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.init(RocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.java:110)

...
08:09:19.673 [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] Shutting down

08:09:19.674 [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.c.p.KafkaProducer - Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.

08:09:19.681 [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] Removing all active tasks []

08:09:19.681 [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] Removing all standby tasks []

08:09:19.681 [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] Removing all standby tasks []

08:09:19.681 [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] Stream thread shutdown complete

08:09:19.681 [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] WARN  o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] Unexpected state transition from ASSIGNING_PARTITIONS to DEAD.

08:09:19.681 [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] WARN  i.a.k.BaseEventsStream - uncaught exception in stream thread ComponentsActivityEventsStream

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: stream-thread [ComponentsActivityEventsStream-608b9f05-0911-4b14-a1b1-37247747686a-StreamThread-2] Failed to rebalance.

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:589)

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:553)

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:527)

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Store ComponentsActivityStore's change log (ComponentsActivityEventsStream-ComponentsActivityStore-changelog) does not contain partition 0

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StoreChangelogReader.validatePartitionExists(StoreChangelogReader.java:87)

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.register(ProcessorStateManager.java:165)
```

Comment: Does this app have all three brokers in its bootstrap-servers list?

Comment: It was the bootstrap-servers list indeed, thanks

Comment: Ok I will post as an answer rather than a comment and please accept as the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that all three brokers are listed in your bootstrap-servers list. If you only list one broker and it happens to be the one that's down, then there is no way for the consumer to get the meta-data it needs to know which of the nodes is the leader for each partition in your topic. If it can't get a valid meta-data response then it wont connect to either of the other two brokers even if they have active copies of the data.